# Module Repeat on selected pages

Tags: dotnetnuke

How to repeat HTML module with content on selected pages?

**Not on all pages**

I know there is an option to display module on all pages under module setting.

Comment: try http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/134599/display-module-on-almost-all-pages and also this http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/135083/hide-and-show-modules-and-pages-in-dotnetnuke

Comment: thanks DH__ let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Add Existing Module" function to handle this.

For this First of all add HTML module on page.
To add that HTML module on another page use Add Existing Module instead of Add New Module.
You can choose page from drop down on which you added HTML module.

Then add to new page. Content will also be placed.